# Centering Nested Floating elements

Tags: css, html

I'm having problems making my floating divs center of the page. 
my structure is like this.

```
<header>
   <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="NavContainer">
         <div class="logo">
          image content here wrapped in a link
         </div>
         <div class="menu">
           Menu links here wrapped in ul's
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

My css currently looks like this for this little part:
however the intention is to just center them on top of each other when I get below 768px width.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    .Menu {
        width: 540px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .NavContainer {
        width: 540px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .Logo {
        width: 540px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #menu-main-menu-1 {
        width: 479.5px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .Menu {
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-left: 1em;
        }

        .NavContainer {
            width:720px;

        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        .Menu {
            margin-top: 6em;
            margin-left: 5em;
            clear: none;
        }

        .NavContainer {
            width:920px;

        }

        #menu-main-menu-1 li:not(:first-child):before {
            content: "";
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .Menu {
            width:625px;
            /*max-width: 625px;
            min-width: 625px;*/
        }

        .NavContainer {
            width:1140px;

        }

        #menu-main-menu-1 li:not(:first-child):before {
            content: "|";
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
    }
```

I have been trying a lot of different approaches to this issue and none of the ones I usually can make work seem to work in this case. what is preventing me to use the float:left with margins-left and margins-right auto margins ?

**Edit:**

I solved it with this css. inspired from the answer I marked as the solution below

```
.NavContainer {
        max-width: 540px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .Logo {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #menu-main-menu-1 {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

Comment: `text-align: center` to `.NavContainer` and try

Comment: @AravindS text-align would only centre text and only within it's own element container. not really applicable to my scenario but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```css
.NavContainer
{
display: -webkit-box; 
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="NavContainer">
         <div class="logo">
          image content here wrapped in a link
         </div>
         <div class="menu">
           Menu links here wrapped in ul's
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: well the logo never centers and the menu never moves to center below the logo either

Comment: I solved my issue And I used some of your approach. I'll make a edit with my solution and mark your answer as the right solution